# Bad interface - Deployment error using Web-Services, Glassfish and JAX-RPC

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I'm trying to deploy a war in glasshfish but it's throwing the error below.
AffiliateInfo is a sub-class of ChannelInfo. It is used as a parameter in one of the web-services. We are using JAX-RPC for invoking the web-services.
Can you give me a hint on where to start looking for the error? I'm lost on this issue and google didn't help either.

```
**[#|2012-10-09T16:59:44.289-0400|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-788;_RequestID=ba9ed32d-c9b1-472c-95da-7a62c9dffdc2;|DPL5035:Error while running ejbc
com.sun.enterprise.deployment.backend.IASDeploymentException: Fatal Error from EJB Compiler -- class com.netsol.partners.intf.responses.AffiliateInfo has interface com.netsol.partners.intf.responses.ChannelInfo as super class**
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.codegen.JaxRpcRICodegen.accept(JaxRpcRICodegen.java:276)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor.visit(WebBundleDescriptor.java:1410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.Application.visit(Application.java:1832)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.codegen.JaxRpcRICodegen.run(JaxRpcRICodegen.java:142)
    at com.sun.ejb.codegen.IASEJBC.doCompile(IASEJBC.java:856)
    at com.sun.ejb.codegen.IASEJBC.ejbc(IASEJBC.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.backend.EJBCompiler.preDeployModule(EJBCompiler.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.backend.EJBCompiler.compile(EJBCompiler.java:212)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.backend.ModuleDeployer.runEJBC(ModuleDeployer.java:817)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.backend.WebModuleDeployer.deploy(WebModuleDeployer.java:184)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.backend.ModuleDeployer.doRequestFinish(ModuleDeployer.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.J2EECPhase.runPhase(J2EECPhase.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentPhase.executePhase(DeploymentPhase.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.executePhases(PEDeploymentService.java:966)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.deploy(PEDeploymentService.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.deploy(PEDeploymentService.java:835)
    at com.sun.enterprise.management.deploy.DeployThread.deploy(DeployThread.java:187)
    at com.sun.enterprise.management.deploy.DeployThread.run(DeployThread.java:225)
|#]
```